# Points as Images

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

Hi is there any way to make the points in the Google Chart API custom images with image urls?

I've been reading up on the docs on customizing points:
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/points

But it doesn't list the parameters available for each option (such as shape-type).

Optimally something like

> pointShape: imageUrl

in the options would be ideal.

Comment: If you scroll down you see shape type `{ pointShape: { type: 'star', sides: 5, dent: 0.05 } }`

Comment: I glanced through the source code and they don't seem to offer such an option out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like google suggests using the overlay approach. By rendering the images on top of the points by getting their X and Y positions.

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/overlays#css2